# WPF ListBox with Multiple ListBoxs inside

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to user ListBox inside ListBox in wpf, This is what I am trying to do

```
public ObservableCollection<Users> List1DS { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Users> List2DS { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Users> List3DS { get; set; }

public class Users
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
//This will have List1DS,List2DS and List3DS
public ObservableCollection<List<Users>> MainDS { get; set; }
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox Margin="25,74,835,-194" x:Name="userslst" ItemsSource="{Binding MainDS}">                      
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List1DS}">
    </ListBox>
</ListBox>
```

There can be zero or multiple items in MainDS,  I want to know is such thing is possible in WPF?
What will be an alternate way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible to display a collection of collections and possibly more easily than you might imagine. You simply have to provide an `ItemTemplate` for the first level items that displays the second level items. Try something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MainDS}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> <!-- Define top level items -->
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"> <!-- Bind to inner collection -->
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate> <!-- Define second level items -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done by putting a listbox in the ItemTemplate of the top listbox and binding it.

But you might want to not do that and go for a treeview/hierarchical template structure as that is already what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I have to display List Horizontally, Can you provide sample code of Treeview/hierachical view?

Comment: To display a list horizontally set the ItemsPanel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx to a Horizontally oriented Stackpanel. For the Treeview and hierachical view check the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx